# Precision of marker being placed on polyline

Tags: interpolation, latitude-longitude

I'm attempting to place a marker on a polyline between two lat/lngs at a given percentage. Now, I know I can do this with google maps, but I need to be able to calculate it in backend code and return the values to be used in an agnostic solution.

My issue is that I have the following calculation to work out the waypoint:

```
function half($startLatLng, $endLatLng, $decimal){
  return {
      'lat': $startLatLng.lat + ($endLatLng.lat - $startLatLng.lat) * $decimal,
      'lng': $startLatLng.lng + ($endLatLng.lng - $startLatLng.lng) * $decimal
  }
}
```

(you can see a working here: https://jsfiddle.net/77my4685/4/)

My only problem is that the precision of the marker placement is out, often by a little bit, sometimes by a lot. If you zoom into the marker on the example you'll see my issue, or see the image below:

[image]

I assumed it was the precision of the lat/lngs but including more decimal places doesn't resolve the issue. Does anyone know why this issue is occurring and how I can go about solving it.

Comment: Your solution assumes a Cartesian globe, but the line is likely following a great circle path, which will deflect to the nearest pole. The *real* math is more than you generally want to do in JavaScript. BTW: If you *think* in terms of "lon-lats" instead of "lat-lons", you'll have an easier time plotting coordinates (X,Y order)

Comment: @Vince - I'm actually using PHP, not that there's much difference. Is there somewhere you could point me to get the answer - or at least help me with the terminology of what I'm looking for? The line is actually a straight line, and not geodesic

Comment: "great circle" is a good start, in the box at the top right

Comment: @Vince, as mentioned though, this polyline doesn't follow the great circle and is a literal straight line.

Comment: You haven't described what software you're using to plot that line, and whether it automatically densifies "straight" arcs for geodetic placement.